# load css via javascript according to screen resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

Statement: Making my website Responsive.

What I have done so far: I've tried using @media queries, making external css pages according to resolution.

Problem: I made 5 style sheets; 1024.css, 1280.css, 1366.css, 1440.css, 1920.css . All seem to work fine except the 1024.css! When I load the website in 1024 resolution it automatically turns to mobile-type site. The nav turns into a button, all the elements get dislocated.

What I'm looking for?: I want to load the css style sheets thru javascript.
For e.g; I want to be able to load 1280.css when the screen's resolution is 1024px .

I'm a beginner at js. So I can't make advanced functions.

But so far I've prepared this algorithm:

```
If (max-width = 1024px){replace style.css with 1280.css}

If (max-width = 1366px){replace style.css with 1366.css}

If (max-width = 1440px){replace style.css with 1440.css}

If (max-width = 1920px){replace style.css with 1920.css}

Else if (max-width = 1280px){replace style.css with 1280.css}
```

PS:I've Searched Google and Stackoverflow and found nothing.

UPDATE: I tried what you said Abhishek Pandey but here is the result . you can check it on http://shalepizza.tk/ 
Im currently working on the index page.

To check the appropriate resolution,  when the page is loaded, press F12 and Ctrl+Shift+M

I link my CSS like this : `<link href="/static/1024.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />`

Comment: Your current approach is the correct one.  You'd be better off finding out why it's not working as expected.

Comment: why use js - why not use media queries? It's unclear what went wrong when you say you've tried that

Comment: Try this https://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Comment: You can load all your css and the media queries will do the job. Loading the main css in js is generaly not an efficient way (inconsistent delay, ..)

Comment: I'd suggest you to share the relevant parts of the code that's not working (how you include your CSS and may be CSS itself and a link to the result page), probably we can help with fixing them. But anyway, you should specify what are you asking about.

Comment: I think you're missing the whole point of Responsive design. The entire idea is that your site scales to the screen size (by specifying box widths as a percentage) and then uses media queries to remove/add/change elements when the screen resolution changes. If you choose a single css when the page loads, what happens when the page resizes?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `html` instead of `js`

```
<link href="/static/1024.css" media="screen and (max-width:1024px)" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
<link href="/static/1366.css" media="screen and (max-width:1366px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

or best option is to use `@media` queries in css file

```
/* min size style*/
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
   /* put your css style in there */
}

/* middle size style */
@media screen and (min-width:321px) {
   /* put your css style in there */
}

/* large size style */
@media screen and (min-width:800px) {
   /* put your css style in there */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May I ask you why you want to use Javascript for that? HTML Has something called `Media Queries` (Rule: `@media`), and with that you can specify which CSS it needs to run by a specific size.

A Media query starts with `@media`. To tell the code that's about the Screen Port, use `screen`. Finish off with `and (min-width:1024px){` and enter your CSS there.

For Example. This is your **style.css**;

```
@media screen and (min-width:1024px){
  background-color:#0f0f1f;
}

@media screen and (min-width:2411px){
  background-color:000000;
}
```

Don't include other css files like this. When you want to do that, you can give the Media attribute in your CSS include.

```
 media="screen and (min-width:1024px)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body  onresize="myFunction()">
function myFunction() {
            var width = window.outerWidth;
            if (width < 960){
                $('link[href="style1.css"]').attr('href','style2.css');
            }else{
                $('link[href="style2.css"]').attr('href','style1.css');
            }
        }
```